# Windows 7 applications not working or installing

Tags: windows-7, windows, uac

I have Windows 7 installed in my system, my problem is that applications don't get the right privileges.

For example, usually when you download an application it will show it's install icon with the "windows shield", my system does not do that, it shows no shield, so when I double click I do not get the UAC prompt nor the installer runs, if it runs it say's that it does not have the right privileges, so in order to install it I have to right click on the icon and choose "Run as Administrator".

This is very frustrating because, some application have to run with admin rights or with the right privileges, for example, Firefox or Skype does not autoupdate because they don't have the right privileges.

In my others systems, this does not happen, just with this computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have admin rights?

Comment: Yes, there's only one account on the system.